# Find position of string elements

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Need some help finding specific letters in string.
I need to find letters "aeiou" in string array and in the output to get just position of that first found letter.
Everything in C#.

```
string array = "Elephants are dangerous";
string letters = "aeiou";

if (array.All(letters.Contains))
{
 Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0}",letters);
}
```

where I made mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want the original string with all the letters not in the filter removed?

Comment: You in your case you want just zero for the `E` from `"Elephant"`, right?

Comment: In this case - yes, I want to get zero.

Comment: Do you need the letter which matches or the index where this letter was found?

Comment: `Elephants are dangerous` does not contain `i`. The result for `.All` check if *false*.

Comment: Try something like this : int[] indexes = array.Select((x, i) => new { letter = x, index = i }).Where(x => letters.Contains(x.letter)).Select(x => x.index).ToArray();

Comment: In addition to what Wiktor mentions `All` only returns `true` when *all* the elements within the source (in your case `letters`) fit the predicate. In your case that means that all vowels are found within `array` which is false as `i` is missing.

Comment: It should also be case insensitive - `if (letters.ToLower().All(p => array.ToLower().Contains(p)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int? minIndex =
 letters
 .Select(l => (int?)array.IndexOf(l))
 .Where(idx => idx != -1)
 .Min();
```

I'd prefer this over any kind of loop solution. This is concise, obviously correct and maintainable in the face of changing requirements.

Comment: nice! But why you are casting into a nullable int?

Comment: Because there might be zero matches and we don't want to use a magic int value. @Mat

Comment: it took me some time to understand the nullable minIndex. That's really smart! I would like to give another upvote ;-)

Comment: @Mat this is a more general pattern that you need any time you need the first item of a non-nullable value-type sequence. So once you know the pattern you recognize it in quite a few places. Here, it's Min instead of FirstOrDefault, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
string array = "Elephants are dangerous";
char[] letters = ("aeiou").ToCharArray(); // make char array to iterate through all characters. you could make this also "inline" in the foreach i just left it her so you see what's going on.

int firstIndex = int.MaxValue;
char firstletter = '?';

foreach (char letter in letters) // iterate through all charecters you're searching for
{
    int index = array
        .ToLower() // to lower -> remove this line if you want to have case sensitive search
        .IndexOf(letter); // get the index of the current letter

    //check if the character is found and if it's the earliest position
    if (index != -1 && index < firstIndex ) 
    {
        firstIndex = index;
        firstletter = letter;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0} @ {1}", firstletter, firstIndex);
```

**EDIT**
if you prefer to go with LINQ:

NOTE: Please take a look at "usr" answer. It's much more cleaner ;-)

```
string array = "Elephants are dangerous";
char[] letters = ("aeiou").ToCharArray();
char firstletter = array.ToLower().First(c => letters.Contains(c));
int firstIndex = array.ToLower().IndexOf(firstletter);
Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0} @ {1}", firstletter, firstIndex);
```

**EDIT2** and here you go with a Regular Expression

```
string array = "Elephants are dangerous";
Match match = Regex.Match(array.ToLower(), "[aeiou]");

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0} @ {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
}
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex